# Change Position of Content in Slider in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i would like to change the position of the content in my ON-OFF Slider.
So that the "ON" content is on the left and the "OFF" content is on the right.
I tried with in CSS with the content-align, but it didnt work the way i wanted.

I couldnt post the question, without adding more details, but i dont know what to say anymore, so i write this short text, to get more words. :D

Thanks for your Answers!

Kind regards
Max

```css
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

    .slider:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        height: 26px;
        width: 26px;
        left: 4px;
        bottom: 4px;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-transition: .4s;
        transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.slider:after {
    content: 'OFF';
    align-content: center;
    
}
input:checked + .slider:after {
    content: 'ON';
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="colorSlider" >
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there…
See the code below, I've added `line-height` on `.slider:after` equal to the total height to verticaly centered the text and `display: block;` + `text-align` right/left depending on the case.

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* only change below this line */

.slider:after {
    font-size: .8em;
    content: 'OFF';
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 34px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

input:checked + .slider:after {
    content: 'ON';
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!-- same HTML code -->
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="colorSlider" >
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Cedric, you made my day.